# Is it possible to delete a key via its value?

Tags: python, json

I am coding a premium feature into my discord bot.I have looked around alot of websites and couldn't find anything.This bot is in python.

Here is what my json file looks like.I have replaced the IDs for privacy reasons.

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "id": 12345
        },
        {
            "id": 1234
        },
        {
            "id": 123
        },
        {
            "id": 12
        },
        {
            "id": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @wkl He's not removing a key from a dictionary, he's removing a dictionary from a list.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe help

```
value_want_to_delete = 123
for i in dct["list"]:
    if i["id"] == value_want_to_delete:
        del i["id"]
print(dct)
```